# iOS 6 UIView properties yield 0

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm trying to do something very, very simple and it doesn't work; so it seems I'm missing something fundamental. I have a single-view application. There's an image in the center. I'd like to move it with user touch. The problem is, I cannot retrieve the coordinate values from the image. Here's what I do:

I have the UIImageView in the storyboard and it's centered with the image file loaded.

I make an outlet to the image view in my ViewController's header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

And naturally, it's connected to the imageView in the storyboard.

In my ViewController's implementation file, in view did load I have this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
CGPoint center = self.imageView.center;
NSLog(@"center: %f, %f", center.x, center.y);
```

The results I have in the console are, unfortunately, both 0. The image view is owned by the main UIView of my ViewController. There seems to be a very, very fundamental problem but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try to log the same in `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead. Do you get the same results ?

Comment: What do u mean by 'Naturally it is connected'? .Make sure the outlet is connected by right clicking on imageview in storyboard and see if it is having reference outlets.

Comment: @Norbert where did he say '_not_ connected' ?

Comment: Sorry, with naturally I meant "of course I've connected". Putting it into viewDidLayoutSubviews solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the imageview from the storyboard to the outlet in the code by ctrl drag from the storyboard to the code?

Comment: Thanks, it was already connected. The problem is solved by accessing the parameters in viewDidLayoutSubviews as commented above.